# Manipulate paging Indexes and Display records in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

First time i am trying  to **implement paging feature in MVC**, and the way it's working is **ex:** a list containce 50 Records and if records to be displayed per page is 10 and finally It will show 5 indexes..but in this case we need to get Entire full list in single time and then devide them to show indexes....but **what if 1000's of records,** in this case i need to get and display 20 rec per page and but indexes to display to user should have 1000/10 means 100 indexes, so that when user click 2 page again i will **fetch next 20 rec from DB**...,to do like this is there any way to customize page indexes (**Html.PagedListPager()**) in **MVC**.

Comment: What about charge pages in the same instead click on pager, just using some ajax and jquery? That´s more newest user interface todays

Comment: can i have any link to know about it ??

Answer (score 0):

To achieve client side load records with more user interface you can use [Data Tables](https://datatables.net/). Just remember, you need to do View, Controller (return JSON),  and JS to work propertly if you want to populate it directly from database